# In python pandas why can't I add more levels to a MultiIndex?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create DataFrames that have three levels. Why does the following function not work twice?

```
def superGroup(dataframe=None,multi_index_name=None):
    out_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dataframe.values,index=dataframe.index,columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[multi_index_name],dataframe.columns]))
    return out_dataframe

ran = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3),columns=["Random"])
ran2 = superGroup(ran,"Hello")
superGroup(ran2,"World")#Does not work
>>>[Out]: NotImplementedError: isnull is not defined for MultiIndex
```

Comment: This works for me on 0.18.1. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I'm also using 0.18.1. So you don't get any errors when you run `superGroup(ran2,"World")` ?

Comment: I just tried upgrading to 0.19.0 and I get the same error. I'm trying to use this command in Jupyter notebook with latest distro of anaconda for windows if that makes any difference.

Comment: No errors, that line works as expected. That was on osx. My advice is to write that as more lines of code, specifically if you pull out the pd.MultiIndex constructor into its own line, I assume that's where the error stems. Also run %debug and poke around. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution I figured out after spending way too much time on this problem. Hope that it helps those out there that have had the same problem.

```
def superGroup(dataframe=None,new_level=None):
    """Returns a dataframe entered but multiindexed with name new level.

    Parameters
    ----------
    dataframe : DataFrame
    new_level : str

    Returns
    -------
    out_df : DataFrame

    """
    if type(dataframe.columns) == pd.indexes.base.Index:
        out_df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe.values,index=dataframe.index,columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[new_level],dataframe.columns]))
        return out_df
    if type(dataframe.columns) == pd.indexes.multi.MultiIndex:
        levels = [list(i.values) for i in dataframe.columns.levels]
        levels = [[new_level]]+levels
        out_df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe.values, index = dataframe.index, columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(levels))
        return out_df
```